# Feasibility of Jade Armor

Tags: materials, armors

For my short story, I want to create a set of Jade armor. I believe Jade is an incredibly impact resistant material, as evident with the Patu club.

I only need one, not mass-production.

**Would a Jade set of armor be pratical?**

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. For light battlefield use, i.e not intended for the front line, but usually in that context if need be. For personal use, and against basic medieval weapons.

Comment: Thanks. I neglected to say, welcome to the site, please enjoy our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways.

Comment: Thank you very much, will do.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on style of armor.

If a crafter wanted to substitute jade for the steel of full gothic plate? No. This would be exceedingly difficult and impractical.

If it was a [lamellar armor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamellar_armour) that used jade for the stitched together plates. Then yes. The Wikipedia article suggest some sets used stone.

Alternatively insetting/inlaying jade into another armor type would be an option. that is using jade as decorative elements of the armor.

Conclusion, yes armor that includes a large enough portion of jade to call is jade armor is feasible.

Comment: Note that jade full body suits were made, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jade_burial_suit but these were made for burial. So you can definitely make lamellar armor with jade. Whether it is useful for combat I have no idea.